# SQL Server trigger fires but with weird results

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a trigger set on update.

If I update 10 rows, the first IF block will insert 10 rows to the changelog
But the next IF statement will only update one row... not 10

The first IF statement `IF @attribute <> 'totalDescriptionLong'` will fire 10 times, just as I expected.

The next IF statement `IF @attribute = 'publishingStatus'`
seems to only fire once... even though I am updating 10 or more rows that qualify for for this...!

I do not understand why one part of the code acts in another way of the other

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[AttributeUpdate] 
ON [DemandwareDataHub].[dbo].     [RETAILEXPORTOUTPUTEXTHUBDWATTRIBUTE]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    DECLARE @nOldValue int, @nNewValue int, 
            @attribute nvarchar(60), @attributeValue nvarchar(1999)

    SELECT @nNewValue = i.Active 
    FROM inserted i

    SELECT @nOldValue = d.Active FROM deleted d
    SELECT @attribute = i.ATTRIBUTE FROM inserted i
Select @attributeValue = i.ATTRIBUTEVALUE from inserted i

IF @attribute <> 'totalDescriptionLong'
BEGIN
    IF @nOldValue <> @nNewValue 
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Inserted)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO [DemandwareDataHub].[dbo].[ChangeLog] (ReferenceRecid, EntityTypeID, ActionType, LogEntryDateTime, PimChangeDateTime, Processed)
            --values(       2, 1, 1, getdate(),getdate(),0)
            SELECT       i.RECID, 1, 1, getdate(), i.TIMESTAMP,0 from Inserted i
            --INSERT INTO ChangeLog (ReferenceRecid, EntityTypeID, ActionType) VALUES        (1, 1, 1)
        END
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Inserted)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO [DemandwareDataHub].[dbo].[ChangeLog] (ReferenceRecid, EntityTypeID, ActionType, LogEntryDateTime, PimChangeDateTime, Processed)
            --values(       2, 1, 1, getdate(),getdate(),0)
            SELECT       i.RECID, 1, 2, getdate(), i.TIMESTAMP,0 from Inserted i
            --INSERT INTO ChangeLog (ReferenceRecid, EntityTypeID, ActionType) VALUES        (1, 1, 1)
        END

    END
END

IF @attribute = 'publishingStatus'
BEGIN
    Declare @Product bigint, @Site nvarchar(60)
    Select @Product = i.PRODUCT from inserted i
    Select @Site = i.SITE from inserted i

    IF @attributeValue = 'proofedPriceCheck' 
    BEGIN
        --This product has been proofed and is ready for a price check
        Declare @PriceLocked bit 
        set @PriceLocked = 0
        SELECT        TOP (1)  @PriceLocked = a.PRICELOCKED
        FROM            RETAILEXPORTOUTPUTEXTDWPRICELOCKED AS a INNER JOIN
                                 SyncPimPriceBooks AS b ON a.ACCOUNTRELATION = b.CountryID
        WHERE        (a.PRODUCT = @Product) AND (b.SiteID = @Site)

        IF @PriceLocked = 1
        BEGIN
            UPDATE       RETAILEXPORTOUTPUTEXTHUBDWATTRIBUTE
            SET                ATTRIBUTEVALUE = 'proofed'
            WHERE        (PRODUCT = @Product) AND (SITE = @Site) AND (ATTRIBUTE = 'publishingStatus') 
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            UPDATE       RETAILEXPORTOUTPUTEXTHUBDWATTRIBUTE
            SET                ATTRIBUTEVALUE = 'proofedPriceNotLocked'
            WHERE        (PRODUCT = @Product) AND (SITE = @Site) AND (ATTRIBUTE = 'publishingStatus') 
        END
    END

END
```

Comment: How are you ascertaining that it is only going into the second IF block only once? I am sure it is obvious to you, but are you getting 10 instances of attribute="publishingStatus" AND attributeValue="proofedPriceCheck"?

Comment: You trigger has a MAJOR flaw. It assumes there will only ever be a single row in inserted. Triggers in sql server fire once per operation. Your triggers need to be set based and not using scalar values pulled from inserted.

Comment: @Forty3 No...  An UPDATE TOP(10) that would qualify for the second IF's would only change one row to either "proofed" or "proofedPriceNotLocked", but it would give me 10 rows in the changelog (the first IF)

Comment: Not sure how you think your first IF statement is firing more than 1 time. I can tell you with absolute certainty that it is not. It will fire one and only 1 time for a single update statement.

Comment: @Sean Lange... Yes, I have read that somewhere as well... But why does it give 10 rows in the changelog then??

Comment: Because that insert is inserting all 10 rows that are in the inserted table. You have control logic that is scalar value based but the contents are a set based insert.

Comment: Honestly this entire trigger looks like it could simplified to a single insert statement to ChangeLog and a single update statement to RETAILEXPORTOUTPUTEXTHUBDWATTRIBUTE

Comment: @Sean I see now... the INSERT/SELECT takes all 10 rows from inserted. But the next does not...
I assumed it ran the code once per row affected... Thanks for clearing that up for me

Comment: @Sean It is not as simple as what you describe there...

Comment: If at all possible you should avoid using names like TIMESTAMP. Not only is that ambiguous (is it datecreated, updated, deleted, some other important date), it is a datatype in sql server that has nothing to do with dates or times.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should be pretty close. I am pretty confident on the insert but the update might take a little tweaking. Of course I am mostly guessing as I don't have table structures and not 100% sure of what you are trying to do. This should be awfully close though.

```
insert [DemandwareDataHub].[dbo].[ChangeLog] 
(
    ReferenceRecid
    , EntityTypeID
    , ActionType
    , LogEntryDateTime
    , PimChangeDateTime
    , Processed
)
select i.RECID
    , 1
    , case when i.Active <> d.Active then 1 else 2 end
    , getdate()
    , i.TIMESTAMP
    , 0
from inserted i
join deleted d on d.RECID = i.RECID --or whatever the primary key column(s) are


 UPDATE RETAILEXPORTOUTPUTEXTHUBDWATTRIBUTE
 set ATTRIBUTEVALUE = case when re.PRICELOCKED = 1 then 'proofed' else 'proofedPriceNotLocked' end
 from inserted i
 join SyncPimPriceBooks b on b.SiteID = i.SITE
 join RETAILEXPORTOUTPUTEXTDWPRICELOCKED re on re.ACCOUNTRELATION = b.CountryID AND re.PRODUCT = i.PRODUCT
 where re.ATTRIBUTE = 'publishingStatus'
```

Comment: has the right idea here. You should never under any circumstances set a value from the inserted or deleted tables to a scalar variable. These are tables that can contain more than one record and the variable can only contain one value. This is the cause of your problem,. You should always join to those tables instead or set the values to a  table variable.